# Jenkins not showing merged report of robot framework

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I have rerun failed test using pybot cmd and afterwards have merged the output xml with new rerun xml . report generated shows pass after re-run in the folder but jenkins still shows failure in its report.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you provided the new xml where the merged result is getting generated in the jenkins or set the path to the new xml. hope this solves your problem